# SQL Select values side by side

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data about users and target points. This is my data.

```
User_   Target
UserA   Target1
UserA   Target2
UserA   Target3
UserB   Target1
UserB   Target3
UserB   Target6
```

I need this output

```
User     FirstTarget     SecondTarget      ThirdTarget       FourthTarget
UserA      Target1          Target2           Target3
UserB      Target1          Target3           Target6
```

Table script for testing

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserTarget](
    [User_] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Target] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserTarget] ([User_], [Target]) VALUES (N'UserA', N'Target1')
INSERT [dbo].[UserTarget] ([User_], [Target]) VALUES (N'UserA', N'Target2')
INSERT [dbo].[UserTarget] ([User_], [Target]) VALUES (N'UserA', N'Target3')
INSERT [dbo].[UserTarget] ([User_], [Target]) VALUES (N'UserB', N'Target1')
INSERT [dbo].[UserTarget] ([User_], [Target]) VALUES (N'UserB', N'Target3')
INSERT [dbo].[UserTarget] ([User_], [Target]) VALUES (N'UserB', N'Target6')
GO
```

Could you help me about sql squery

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT X.USER_,
MAX
(
  CASE
     WHEN X.XCOL=1 THEN X.TARGET
     ELSE ''
  END
)FIRST_TARGET,
MAX
(
 CASE
   WHEN X.XCOL=2 THEN X.TARGET
   ELSE ''
 END
)SECOND_TARGET,
MAX
(
 CASE
   WHEN X.XCOL=3 THEN X.TARGET
   ELSE ''
 END
)THIRD_TARGET,
MAX
(
 CASE
  WHEN X.XCOL=4 THEN X.TARGET
  ELSE ''
 END
)FOURTH_TARGET
FROM
(
   SELECT T.[User_],T.[Target],
   ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.USER_ ORDER BY T.[Target] ASC)XCOL
  FROM [dbo].[UserTarget] AS T
)X
GROUP BY X.User_
```

You can use something like this. If the number of targets is undefined then please google "dynamic pivot SQL Server"

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dynamic SQL PIVOT

```
/*Declare Variable*/  
DECLARE @Pivot_Column [nvarchar](max);  
DECLARE @Query [nvarchar](max);  
  
/*Select Pivot Column*/  
SELECT @Pivot_Column= COALESCE(@Pivot_Column+',','')+ QUOTENAME([Target]) FROM  
(SELECT DISTINCT [Target] FROM [UserTarget])Tab  
  
/*Create Dynamic Query*/  
SELECT @Query='SELECT [User_], '+@Pivot_Column+'FROM   
(SELECT [User_] , [Target] FROM [UserTarget] )Tab1  
PIVOT  
(  
MAX(Target) FOR [Target] IN ('+@Pivot_Column+')) AS Tab2  
ORDER BY Tab2.[User_]'  
  
/*Execute Query*/  
EXEC  sp_executesql  @Query
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ICKjHeYn)

Source: [Pivot in SQL Server](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f0b2ed/pivot-and-unpovit-in-sql-server/)

As @Larnu suggested

[Fiddle with STRING_AGG](https://dbfiddle.uk/3HLyV1Zy)

Note: You can use STRING_AGG starting from [SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Using the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.

Comment: @Larnu like this [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3HLyV1Zy)